# SELECTing user with earliest time and joining with other data

Tags: sql, oracle, select, plsql, inline-view

I have an Oracle database where I'm trying to select a `user` field from the earliest row (based on a `time` field) where certain conditions are met, and I don't know how to do it.  Here's the gist of my query:

```
SELECT id,
       CASE WHEN value = 'xyz'
            THEN 'Pending'
            ELSE 'Not Pending'
       END AS status,
       time
FROM table1
INNER JOIN ...
WHERE subject IN (...) AND
      field = 'Status'
```

My problem is I don't know how to SELECT `user` and get only the value from the row with the earliest `time` value matching the WHERE conditions.  I don't think I can use `HAVING` since I'm not doing any aggregate functions in my SELECT.  The 'earliest `time` value' condition needs to apply *only* to the selection of the `user` field, i.e. I want `id` and `value` to be selected for *all* values of the `time` field.

I was thinking I could keep the SELECT statement I have above and then JOIN with another SELECT statement that gets the particular `user` I want.

```
SELECT id, status, time, user
FROM (
       ...query above...
     ),
     (
       SELECT user
       FROM table1
       WHERE subject in (...) AND
             field = 'Status' AND
             ROWNUM = 1
       ORDER BY time ASC
     )
```

However, this only gets one value for `user` overall, and there should be a separate `user` value for each `id` SELECTed in my first query.  How do I limit my `SELECT user` query by the other query's `id` field?  Is this even the right approach to get what I want?

Comment: Could you post the sample data & expected output as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  id,
        CASE WHEN value = 'xyz'
             THEN 'Pending'
             ELSE 'Not Pending'
        END AS status,
        time,
        FIRST_VALUE(user) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY time) AS first_user
FROM    table1
INNER JOIN
        ...
WHERE   subject IN (...) AND
        field = 'Status'
```

Comment: Based on http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10759/functions049.htm I think this is exactly what I need.  :)  I have a limited interface through which I can access the database, and the query is currently timing out...  I'm investigating options like `UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` and others at http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10759/functions001.htm#i81407 to try and make it run faster.

Comment: When you omit the `ROWS` / `RANGE` clause, it defaults to `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`.